# TVMAZE API: Can't split episodes by season jQuery, AJAX, WordPress

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, wordpress, api

I'm very new in JSON, as well as, in regard to the usage of the API. I managed to grab data from TVMAZE thanks to AJAX query. By the way, I use WordPress.

I grabbed the episodes this way:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": ""+myscripts_vars.url1+"", 
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {},
    "data": "{}"
  }

  $('.some-button').click(function() {
  $.ajax(settings)
   .done(function(data){
     $.each(data, function (i, value) { 
     $('.episodelist').append('<tr><td id="episode_n">' + value.number + 
  '</td><td id="episode_name">' + value.name + '</td><td 
  id="episode_air_date">' + value.airdate + '</td><td 
  id="episode_season">' + value.season + '</td></tr>');


  });
  })
```

P.s.: +myscripts_vars.url1+ -- I transfered this variable thanks to wp_localize_script

But, as a result, I have a list consisting of 4 rows:

- N Title Air Date Season 1
- N Title Air Date Season 1
- N Title Air Date Season 1
- N Title Air Date Season 1
- N Title Air Date Season 1
- N Title Air Date Season 2
- N Title Air Date Season 2
- N Title Air Date Season 2
- N Title Air Date Season 2
- N Title Air Date Season 2

However, my goal is to split this episode list by seasons. I can't figure out how to doing it both thanks to jQuery or by means of the API.

All I need is to get as a result the table like this:

Season 1

- N Title AirDate

Season 2

- N Title AirDate

Season N

- N Title AirDate

P.p.s: Ideally, I want to use jQuery accordion for all these data.

So, my questions are the following:

1. How do I need to grab the episodes correctly (if I made some mistakes)?
2. Is it a good idea to transfer variables between my PHP code and AJAX via wp_localize_script?
3. Is there a way to make the correct API query to split my episodes by seasons on the "API side?"
4. Is there any method to make the POST request instead of the GET one?
5. Ideally, I want to see the jQuery accordion with all the episodes split by seasons. So, if anyone might assist me with this I would appreciate.

To take a look at the JSON response, use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://api.tvmaze.com/seasons/6/episodes",
"method": "GET",
"headers": {},
"data": "{}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
});

});
```

Thanks everyone for the assistance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that by using multiple endpoints and creating your own map of seasons to episodes.

- `/shows/:id/seasons` use the show id to get the [seasons](https://www.tvmaze.com/api#show-seasons) for that show, this returns  a list of the seasons and their
  season id's
- `/seasons/:id/episodes` use the season id to get the [episodes](https://www.tvmaze.com/api#season-episodes) for a season, this returns a list of the episodes for a season

once you have this you can create a seasonsMap of this type `{seasonNumber: [seasonEpisodes]}` or any other structure that helps you associate episodes to a season.

with the seasonsMap you can iterate it and create the template needed by jquery accordion

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>First header</h3>
  <div>First content panel</div>
  <h3>Second header</h3>
  <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

here's an example of how i did it hope this helps

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // helper functions to query api.tvmaze
  async function getSeasons(showId) {
    return await $.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${showId}/seasons`);
  }

  async function getEpisodesForSeason(seasonId) {
    return await $.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/seasons/${seasonId}/episodes`);
  }

  // helper function to group seasons to episodes for given show using show's id
  async function createSeasonsMap(showId) {

    const seasons = await getSeasons(showId);

    const seasonsMap = await seasons.reduce(async function(acc, season) {
      const _acc = await acc;
      const episodes = await getEpisodesForSeason(season.id);
      _acc[`season-${season.number}`] = episodes;
      return _acc;
    }, {});

    return seasonsMap;
  }

  // helper function to create html template required by jquery accordian
  function createAccordianElement($el, title, content) {

    // create accordian header
    const $header = $(`<h3> ${title} </h3>`);
    const $content = $("<div></div>");

    // create list items
    const $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
    $ul.append(content.map(x => $(`<li> ${x.name} </li>`)));

    // add to accordian 
    $content.append($ul);
    $el.append($header);
    $el.append($content);

  }

  // creates accordian ui for show 1 
  const seasons = createSeasonsMap(1).then(function(seasonsMap) {
    const $accordion = $("#accordion");
    $accordion.empty(); // clear 

    Object.keys(seasonsMap).forEach(function(season) {
      createAccordianElement($accordion, season, seasonsMap[season]);
    });
    
    $accordion.accordion();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
</div>
```

making one request and using the fact that each episode object has the season it belongs to using that to create a seasonsMap

```js
async function getEpisodes(showId) {
  return await $.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${showId}/episodes`);
}

async function createSeasonsMap(showId) {

  const episodes = await getEpisodes(showId);

  const seasonsMap = await episodes.reduce(async function(acc, episode) {
    const _acc = await acc;
    if (_acc[`season-${episode.season}`] == null) {
      _acc[`season-${episode.season}`] = [];
    }
    _acc[`season-${episode.season}`].push(episode);
    return _acc;
  }, {});

  return seasonsMap;
}

createSeasonsMap(1).then(console.log)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

then you can use seasonsMap to create an accordion later on or asynchronously in the reduce. Here's the same code inserted into my first ex:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // helper functions to query api.tvmaze
  async function getSeasons(showId) {
    return await $.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${showId}/seasons`);
  }

  async function getEpisodesForSeason(seasonId) {
    return await $.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/seasons/${seasonId}/episodes`);
  }

  async function getEpisodes(showId){
   return await $.get(`https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${showId}/episodes`);
  }
  // helper function to group seasons to episodes for given show using show's id
  async function createSeasonsMap(showId) {

    const episodes = await getEpisodes(showId);

    const seasonsMap = await episodes.reduce(async function(acc, episode) {
      const _acc = await acc;
      if(_acc[`season-${episode.season}`] == null){
       _acc[`season-${episode.season}`] = [];
      }
      _acc[`season-${episode.season}`].push(episode);
      return _acc;
    }, {});

    return seasonsMap;
  }

  // helper function to create html template required by jquery accordian
  function createAccordianElement($el, title, content) {

    // create accordian header
    const $header = $(`<h3> ${title} </h3>`);
    const $content = $("<div></div>");

    // create list items
    const $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
    $ul.append(content.map(x => $(`<li> ${x.name} </li>`)));

    // add to accordian 
    $content.append($ul);
    $el.append($header);
    $el.append($content);

  }

  // creates accordian ui for show 1 
  const seasons = createSeasonsMap(1).then(function(seasonsMap) {
    const $accordion = $("#accordion");
    $accordion.empty(); // clear 
    Object.keys(seasonsMap).forEach(function(season) {
      createAccordianElement($accordion, season, seasonsMap[season]);
    });
    $accordion.accordion();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Jonathan Portorreal! I appreciate for your assistance. You made almost exactly what I need. But I can't realize how. It seems that you've used jQuery GET instead of the jQuery AJAX GET. I don't know such a syntax at all. Can you please explain me would it affect the site speed if to make two API requests like in your example? Can I make 5-10 requests using such a method without affection to the speed?

Comment: @AlexCardo ajax get is just shorthand for the .ajax, i looked over the docs again and noticed your original endpoint that you posted has season info in it already so i guess you dont need to make the 2 requests, but one and transform the results to be more usuable, i updated answer